# Is it possible to capture any traceback generated by a Python application?

Tags: python

I've been searching google for a way to somehow capture any traceback generated by a Python application.

I'd like to send an email/slack/notification to myself if *any* error occurs which generates a traceback (instead of relying on users to report issues to me).

I still haven't found anything [which doesn't involve you doing a try/except](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442459-email-pretty-tracebacks-to-yourself-or-someone-you/). But of course I can't put everything I do inside individual try/except clauses since I'm writing applications which launch a UI (PySide/PyQt4/PySide2/PyQt5) and could error on user interaction.

Is this possible, and if so how can I capture any traceback generated?

Comment: You could parse the logs which would detect an exception and send you an email. Or, you can try using sentry https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentry?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do it by creating custom [`sys.excepthook`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

```
import sys
import traceback


def report_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    # just a placeholder, you may send an e-mail here
    print("Type", exc_type)
    print("Value", exc_value)
    print("Tb", ''.join(traceback.format_tb(exc_tb)))


def custom_excepthook(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
    report_exception(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
    sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)  # run standard exception hook


sys.excepthook = custom_excepthook

raise RuntimeError("I want to report exception here...")
```

For pretty-printing traceback objects refer to [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module.